# MVC3 SSL Trouble - Can't switch from HTTPS to HTTP when SSL is not required

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, https

I'm trying to get my MVC3 site to redirect from HTTPS back to HTTP when the user browses to a page where it's not required (and they aren't logged in). I Don't want to have the load of running the whole site HTTPS but it's looking like thats the way I'll have to go.

I've been having loads of trouble with remote debug and symbols, but having gone back in time to 1985 and using message box equivalents to debug with I've come to the following conclusion:

```
if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor
     .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequireHttpsAttribute), true)
     .Any()
   )
{
   return true;
}
return false;
```

Always returns false.

The controller def starts as:

```
[FilterIP(
    ConfigurationKeyAllowedSingleIPs = "AllowedAdminSingleIPs",
    ConfigurationKeyAllowedMaskedIPs = "AllowedAdminMaskedIPs",
    ConfigurationKeyDeniedSingleIPs = "DeniedAdminSingleIPs",
    ConfigurationKeyDeniedMaskedIPs = "DeniedAdminMaskedIPs"
)]
[RequireHttps]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
```

And it doesn't seem to work for any actions in this controller (although they do get successfully routed to SSL).

Any suggestions? I'd love to see an answer for what I perceive as my own nubery ;)

Comment: Out of security concerns, why do you want to switch to non-ssl? Keep in mind auth tokens and session ids can be sent over non ssl and session hijacking can easily occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was discovered to be related to the bindings on the server published to. We use the same server for stage and production, and the stage https bindings were not set, so whenever it was calling an https page it was resolving into our production site (which looked the same so it was hard to spot).

Once I added a binding it was all solved. My code was ok...

Answer (score 0):

[Custom NotRequreHttpsAttribute tutorial](http://amilagm.com/2012/04/configure-asp-net-mvc-controller-to-use-ssl-or-not-to-use-ssl/)

I use the above link post to implement my custom attribute, and redirect from https to http. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, although I want to debug the getcustomattributes fail any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, no suggestion. I don't know why the getcustomattriutes failed either.